# Android: Obfuscate library code and publish to jcenter

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard, jcenter

I am able to publish an Android Library to jCenter. but when using the library I am able to see original code, Not the obfuscated version.

I have added a few rules in proguard-rules for library module and executing  ./gradlew clean :library:build generateRelease,

Is this the right approach? If yes, then there should be some issue with my proguard-rules.

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` and your proguard rules